# Branches in Inline Functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline, compiler-optimization

I think I have a serious compiler mistrust. Do branches inside inline functions get optimized out if they have constant results?

For the example function:

```
#define MODE_FROM_X_TO_Y 0
#define MODE_FROM_Y_TO_X 1

inline void swapValues(int & x, int & y, int mode) {
    switch(mode) {
        case MODE_FROM_X_TO_Y:
            y = x;
            break;
        case MODE_FROM_Y_TO_X:
            x = y;
            break;
    }
}
```

Would:

```
swapValues(n,m,MODE_FROM_X_TO_Y);
```

be optimized as:

```
n = m;
```

Comment: It's going to depend on the actual compiler you are using, but generally the answers would be Yes and No.

Comment: a simple test you can do is compile your code in release version and try to put a break point in the line of code you think the compiler is optimizing, if you can't put a break point there you can have a look in the error, sometimes (not always) the compiler will say it can't hit that break point because the code is being optimized. however this will not always work, the only way to know is go to the assembly

Comment: Having just tested this with clang and `-O3`: yes, it gets optimized completely.

Answer (score 3):

First off, it won't even compile (until you add a return type).

Secondly, `swap` is an awesomely badly chosen name (since it doesn't do a `swap`, and conflicts with the `std::swap` name).

Thirdly, head over to http://gcc.godbolt.org/:

**<kbd>[Live On Godbolt](http://goo.gl/GuA7Ub)</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: That's a great site, thanks for the link.

Also, I was just being quick in terms of the example function. I'll fix that right now.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the answers to these questions are compiler dependent.

To get an answer to your question with your code, with your compiler (and compiler version), and compiler settings (e.g. optimisation flags) you will need to examine the code output by the compiler.

Branches in any code - not just within inlined functions - can potentially be "optimized out" if the compiler can detect that the same branch is always followed.

Some modern compilers are also smart enough to not inline a function declared `inline` if it evaluates another function as a better candidate for inlining.    A number of modern compilers can do a better job making such decisions than a typical C/C++ programmer.